# Proving $\lceil{\lg n}\rceil!$ is not polynomially bounded.

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, asymptotics

I know this question has already been asked a lot of times before as mentioned:

[Polynomial bounds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372519/polynomial-bounds)

[Is $\lceil{\lg n}\rceil!$ polynomially bounded?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123688/is-lceil-lg-n-rceil-polynomially-bounded)

But what I could not understand it is how to prove that it is not polynomial bounded.
According to the Book Introduction to Algorithms:

We say that a
function $f(n)$ is polynomially bounded if $f(n)=  O(n^k) $ for some constant $k$.

Thereby using Stirling approximation I could easily get:
$(\lg n)^{\lg n}$ omitting the constant values: $e^{-\lg n}\sqrt{2\pi\lg n}$

So for $\lceil\lg n\rceil!$ to be proved as a polynomial it should follow:

There would
exist constants $c$, $k$ and $n_0$ such that $0\le\lceil\lg n\rceil!\le 
 c {n^k} $ for all $n\ge
 n_0$

But do not know how to prove it further. Could someone please help me out in figuring this out.
Thank you.

Comment: is $\lg n = \frac{\ln n}{\ln 10}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the answers that you cited the problem is essentially reduced to studying the expression
$$\log(n)^{\log(n)} = \exp  ( \log(n) \log(\log(n))) = n^{\log(\log(n))}.$$
Since 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\log(\log(n))=\infty
$$
there cannot exist a constant $C>0$ and $k$ such that
$$
n^{\log(\log(n))}\le Cn^k.
$$
In other words, $n^{\log(\log(n))}$ is not polynomially bounded.

Comment: If you could let me know why we did exp$(\lg n \lg(\lg n))$?

Comment: We wanted to represent $\log(n)^{\log(n)}$ as a power of $n$, in order to compare it with $n^k$ later, so we used the identity $\log (a^b)=\exp(b\log a)$.

Comment: Ok thank you. Got it.

Comment: Also could you please explain me this statement if you do not mind: $\Theta \left(n^{\log \log n}\right)$  is polynomially lower bounded but not upper bounded. I am confused on how the author conclude that it falls in Omega?